# lodash _.filter for conditions optionally based on arrays?

Tags: javascript, filter, lodash

The _.filter function works great for objects containing single items as the values.

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false }
];

_.filter(users, function(o) { return !o.active; });
// => objects for ['fred']

// The `_.matches` iteratee shorthand.
_.filter(users, { 'age': 36, 'active': true });
// => objects for ['barney']
```

Is there a way to apply the same function to objects with arrays as values?

I'd like to get any elements that may contain the value, including if it is one of the values of an array:

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true, 'colors': ['blue', 'yellow'] },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false, 'colors': ['blue', 'purple'] }
  { 'user': 'mary',   'age': 40, 'active': false, 'colors': ['blue', 'grey'] }
];

_.filter(users, { 'colors': 'blue' });
// => all objects as they all contain 'blue'

_.filter(users, { 'active': false , 'colors': 'blue' });
// => objects for 'fred' and 'mary'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put brackets around the color you want to filter on: `{ 'colors': ['blue'] }`

```js
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true, 'colors': ['blue', 'yellow'] },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false, 'colors': ['blue', 'purple'] },
  { 'user': 'mary',   'age': 40, 'active': false, 'colors': ['grey', 'blue'] }
];

console.log(_.filter(users, { 'colors': ['blue'] }));
console.log(_.filter(users, { 'active': false, 'colors': ['blue'] }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Would this work if `blue` was not in the `0`th index?

Comment: Thank you, this "magically" worked despite not being described in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

yes, just add a condition inside the callback function `o.colors.indexOf(color)` 
 to check if `color` is in the array, this will return inactive users having `purple` color :

```
_.filter(users, (o) => { return !o.active && o.colors.indexOf('purple') > -1  });
```

[Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

[Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
let users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true, 'colors': ['blue', 'yellow'] },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false, 'colors': ['blue', 'purple'] },
  { 'user': 'mary',   'age': 40, 'active': false, 'colors': ['blue', 'grey'] }
];

_.filter(users, { 'colors': 'blue' });
// => all objects as they all contain 'blue'

// using Array.indexOf
let myUsers = _.filter(users, (o) => { return !o.active && o.colors.indexOf('purple') > -1  }); 

// using Array.includes ( ES6 )
let myUsers2 = _.filter(users, (o) => { return !o.active && o.colors.includes('purple') }); 

console.log('using IndexOf() : ', myUsers)
console.log('using includes() : ', myUsers2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: With ES6, you can use [`o.colors.includes('purple')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yeah thnx for the hint, i updated the answer to have richer content :)